# Get abbreviation from unit with UnitsNet (C#)

Tags: c#

I am working with [UnitsNet](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet).

I wonder how I can get the unit abbreviation from the unit enum value

Example:

```
var myUnit=LengthUnit.Meter; //Meter
var myAbbreviation = ... ; //abbreviation "m"
```

Could you please help me?

[EDIT]
I found a solution. No idea if it is acceptable...

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Default implementation of IUnit based on UnitsNet
 /// </summary>
 public class UnitImpl: IUnit 
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Enum from UnitsNet (example: VolumeUnit.Liter)
     /// </summary>
     public Enum UnitValue { get; }

     public string Abbreviation =>
        UnitAbbreviationsCache.Default.GetDefaultAbbreviation(UnitValue.GetType(), Convert.ToInt32(UnitValue));

     /// <summary>
     /// Name of the unit
     /// </summary>
     public string Name => UnitValue.ToString();

     public UnitImpl(Enum unit)
     {
         UnitValue = unit;
     }
 }
```

Comment: yes sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

In UnitsNet there is the `QuantityFormatter` class that manage the formatting stuff for the library.

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/blob/master/UnitsNet/QuantityFormatter.cs) you will find the various types of format strings that you could use, one of them is `a` (or `A`) that is the abbreviated unit for the quantities.

So you could use any of these methods to get the desired value:

- `@QuantityFormatter.Format(myValue, "a")`
- `$"{myValue:a}"`
- `string.Format("{0:a}", myValue)`

You could also define an extension so that you can use `myValue.GetUnitName()`:

```cs
public static class UnitHelpers {
    public static string GetUnitName<T>(this T value) where T : IFormattable, IQuantity {
        return $"{value:a}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest I could get, where your code has to know which type your unit is (Mass, Length, etc..)

```
var myUnit = LengthUnit.Meter; //Meter
string myAbbreviation = Length.GetAbbreviation(myUnit); //m
```

Example for mass:

```
var MyMassUnit = MassUnit.Kilogram; //Kilogram
string MyMassAbbreviation = Mass.GetAbbreviation(MyMassUnit); //kg
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But the problem is that my class has no idea about the type of the enum (lengthunit or volumeunit .. etc)
But I think I found a solution. See me edit.